# Search bar’s tooltip popup hasn’t closing on tapping on many areas

Tags: bug, design, search, ios, touch-screen

When the top bar tooltip for the search is visible tapping anywhere on marked with FHRC areas doesn’t close the tooltip (FHBC) on my iPad:

> [image: popup]

Comment: I actually can't repro this right now... is it fixed for you? AH!!! I see, it's on iPad. Yes, I see that.

Comment: @Catija I'll check later today, don't have iPad right now to check.

Comment: It's OK! I missed that it was iOS-specific. I can repro on my iPad. :)